# Error integrating Aurasma: Resource Integrity check failed

Tags: android, augmented-reality, aurasma

I am trying to Integrating Aurasma in my application. All application work well but on Aurasma part when I launch it on Button Click IT throws a message on splash screen as "An error is occurred" and on Log Cat It shows "Resource integrity check failed" I am wondering why this is happening, I integrate aurasma on a separate application without any click event, it launches directly then it works but in side of my application its not working, why. I am sure about these points:

- Make sure the SDK tools are version 14 or above.
- Check the Eclipse project to make sure that AurasmaKernel is set as required on the build path
- Check that the AurasmaKernel package has built properly in Eclipse (also try building it manually)
- Make sure that the kernel is correctly extracted, and that your resources don't clash with any of the packaged library

But yet it not working same error message.

Code for launching Aurasma is below:

```
  aurasmaIntent = AurasmaIntentFactory.getAurasmaLaunchIntent(HomeActivity.this,
 getString(R.string.app_name), getString(R.string.app_version));
 } catch (AurasmaLaunchException e) {
 Log.e("AKTest", "Error getting intent", e);
 showDialog(DIALOG_ERROR);
 return;
}

 if (DELAY_START) {
 AurasmaSetupCallback callback = new AurasmaSetupCallback() {

  @Override
  public void onLoaded() {
   dismissDialog(DIALOG_PROGRESS);
   startActivity(aurasmaIntent);
  }

@Override
public void onLoadWarning(final int code) {
 Log.w("AKTest", "Preload warning: " + code);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFail(final int code) {
 Log.e("AKTest", "Preload error: " + code);
 dismissDialog(DIALOG_PROGRESS);
 showDialog(DIALOG_ERROR);
}
 };
 showDialog(DIALOG_PROGRESS);

 AurasmaIntentFactory.startAurasmaPreload(getApplicationContext(), aurasmaIntent,
 callback);
 } else {
  startActivity(aurasmaIntent);
}
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I got stuck as well now :-S My error *** 09-27 12:13:20.843: E/AKTest(2980): Error getting intent ***

Answer (score 1):

If you change some resource from Aurasma library(layout or string) you will get this error - "An error is occurred". Library checks resources on Aurasma start. Don't change or delete any files.

Another thing that can cause error is:

```
aurasmaIntent = AurasmaIntentFactory.getAurasmaLaunchIntent(HomeActivity.this,
    getString(R.string.app_name), getString(R.string.app_version));
```

Here second parameter is userAgentName. This is the name of your app that you have from [studio.aurasma.com](http://studio.aurasma.com). In "Make your own app" you can see the application name - this name is connected with your application but can be different.

Answer (score 0):

check your minSdkVersion in the manifest

android:minSdkVersion="8"